# Numpy, pandas, Matlab, R rolling sum inconsistency, with varying length of history

Tags: matlab, numpy, pandas, numerical-methods, moving-average

I'm testing a simulation on dateranges, in such a way that I expect a caluculation for a given date returning the same number, irrespective of the daterange which I calculate the given batch for.

That is, if I call the system for the range of 1990-2000, then the 1995.07.01 result should be the same as when calling the system for 1995-1996. Should be quite basic, I thought...

The problem is that fast rolling window implementations accumulate rounding errors, which do depend on the length of history outside the rolling window. So when I do a 20 day moving sum for 1995.07.01, the result will have more accumulated rounding error in the case of running the rolling sum operation on a timeseries since 1990.

Here is an example, where I would expect the non-nan results to match exactly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([xrange(7)]).astype('float64').T
df = np.sqrt(df)
roll1_df = pd.rolling_sum(df, window=3)
roll2_df = pd.rolling_sum(df.iloc[3:, :], window=3)
```

But I get the rounding error:

```
roll1_df - roll2_df

              0
0           NaN
1           NaN
2           NaN
3           NaN
4           NaN
5  8.881784e-16
6  1.776357e-15
```

The example is using Python/pandas, but the issue is the same in any number crunching software, hence I'm happy for ideas, in pandas, numpy, Matlab, R ... or based on pure theory.

It would be important to keep the performance advantage of the fast rolling operations, i.e. avoiding simply summing the last N values for all dates (which would be O(N) times slower than the faster rolling window implementations).

**Edit: Solution**

I chose the following solution after all, taking pandas apart and putting back together with a bit of rounding in rolling_sum:

```
rolling_sum_stable_df = _rolling_func(
    lambda *arg_l: np.round(roll_sum(*arg_l), decimals=11),
    'Stable rolling_sum'
)
```

Could convert to float32 first before rolling_sum(), then convert back to float64, but would lose more digits then. Disadvantage of the approach is that I have to do this for rolling_cov and other rolling functions too, which are slightly more involved.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what exactly you are summing. But if you want exact equality between two results - than floating point numbers will never make you happy. You'll either have to use integer types or an implementation of "almost-equal" instead of "equal".

Comment: You can use [`np.isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) : `np.isclose(roll1_df[3:], roll2_df )` this shows the last 2 values are close enough to be considered equal

Comment: Tried this few years ago. Unfortunately numerical errors are non-linear in the system, i.e. a difference of 1e-16 can cause large changes in later numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in python `decimal` module.  It does not have floating point rounding errors.  It is slower, however, than floating point numbers.